# split Arabic sentence to letters and keep Diacritics

Tags: c#, split, arabic, diacritics

I have Arabic sentence written with diacritics: `"مَرْحَبَا كَيْفَ حَالُك"`.
I want to split it to letters, so I used this code:

```cs
string text = "مَرْحَبَا كَيْفَ حَالُك";

char[] word = text.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word[i]);
}
```

but it splits letters from diacritics.
I want it to be like this

```
مَ
رْ
حَ
بَ
ا
 
كَ
يْ
فَ
 
حَ
ا
لُ
ك
```